# Avoid repopulation of django database

Tags: django, docker, populate

I have a population script which must run the first time that the application is started. Only the first time.

The application is running as a docker container. The way I am doing this at the moment is, before starting the django application, the container runs the population scripts.

This has the consequence that restart the container runs the population scripts again, causing duplicated entries.

What strategy could I use to avoid repopulating the database? I have a couple of ideas:

1. mark in the container filesystem. Very easy to implement, but I am not sure if this will survive a container restart? I have anyway discarded this because it will definitely not survive a container rebuild.
2. mark in the database. This seems too complex to implement, but seems the most robust solution: it will only run whenever the DB is not marked, and it will automatically detect whenever the DB has been scratched.
3. mark in a persistent volume. This is my preferred solution. The only minor problem is that scratching the database will not be detected (but I can manage that manually)

Do you have any other idea how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have to run migrations anyway when you start your application the first time, you could create a [Data Migration](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/migrations/#data-migrations) and rely on Django's migration mechanism to ensure it is only run once on the database.

Comment: Interesting, I will give this a try. I assume this is tracked at the database level by the django migrations system, so this is exactly what I need. I obviously need this data migration *after* the initial schema migrations have run (I need the tables in the database), so I will need to make sure that the order is respected. I assume this will be achieved my naming my data migration with the right prefix.

Comment: Yes, there is a table `django_migrations` that contains all migrations. You don't have to prefix your migration, you just create it after you have created the schema migrations for your models.

Comment: Not sure about order. Let's say I test this in my integration system, where initial migrations have run, and my data migration is run after it. This will work. But how will django know the order of the migrations when running against the production system, which has not yet been setup at all?

Comment: Each migration has an explicit dependency to the previous migration (except the initial migration, of course)

Comment: You are right. Another issue: apparently I can not run queries while running migrations, and my population script is based on queries in order to link related models. Any idea how to overcome this? This is the problem I get: `An error occurred in the current transaction. You can't execute queries until the end of the 'atomic' block.`